# How to run an exe file using C# in console application

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to run an exe file in my console application which is located on a network drive.
So what needs to happen is the app needs to map the network drive with a drive letter by using this code:

```
 private static void MapDrive()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "net.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @"use w: \\<server>\CompanyData\W10 /user:Administrator Password";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
    }
```

This works great and the drive letter is mapped.
Now the problem I am facing is to run the exe file with in this mapped drive.
I have tried the below but does not seem to work:

```
 private static void RunSetup()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @"w:\setup.exe";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();;
    }
```

Nothing seems to happen in regards to launching the exe file.
I need to know what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Try just setting `FileName` directly to the setup program. Additionally, unless the setup program will automatically run a silent setup, you might consider not using the Hidden window style for the setup program.

Comment: Run setup.exe, not cmd.exe.

Comment: What does `System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` mean @Keith?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Either include the "/c" argument

```
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"/c w:\setup.exe";
```

or set `FileName` directly to the setup.exe

```
startInfo.FileName = "w:\setup.exe";
```

as mentioned in the comments

Comment: Do not encourage the former. This habit people have of running `cmd.exe` is weird and should not be encouraged unless it is truly needed (which is rare, and not the case here).